# Odoo 10 - Many2one filters xml

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm following my Python program and I'm trying to recover only records found via Python functions.

Here are my functions:

```
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def get_foyer(self):
    if self.partner_id:
        actually_partner_id = self.partner_id.name
        if actually_partner_id:
            records_foyer_id = self.env['horanet.relation.foyer'].search([('partner_id', '=', actually_partner_id)],
                                                                         order="id desc")
            for rec in records_foyer_id:
                self.foyer_id = rec.id

@api.onchange('foyer_id')
def get_responsibles_members_foyer(self):
    if self.foyer_id:
        actually_foyer = self.foyer_id.foyer_id
        if actually_foyer:
            domain = [('foyer_id', '=', actually_foyer.id)]
            records_foyer_id = self.env['horanet.relation.foyer'].search(domain)
            for rec in records_foyer_id:
                print " " + rec.partner_id.name
                if rec.partner_id:
                    domain_partner = [('foyer_id', '=', self.foyer_id.foyer_id.id),
                                      ('is_responsible', '=', True)]
                    records_partner_id = self.env['horanet.relation.foyer'].search(domain_partner)
                    for rec_partner in records_partner_id:
                        if rec_partner.partner_id:
                            self.school_responsible_partner1 = rec_partner.partner_id.id
```

These functions serve two purposes:

-> automatically fill in the field foyer_id (recovery of a home)
-> automatically fill in the field school_responsible_partner1 (recovery of the member responsible for this household)

Until then no problem.

However, when I roll out my 2 many2one fields, I get all homes or all members of any household.
Do you have an idea to see only the recordings that interest me?

Attention, the same person can have 2 homes so I must be able to choose one of them.

I heard that it could happen in xml. But how ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use domain in .xml file. Like this:

```xml
<field name="foyer_id" domain="[('partner_id', '=', partner_id)]"/>
```

You will then be able to choose foyer_id only that has a partner_id you have already assigned. But if you haven't chosen any partner_id, you will have no available foyer_id. In that case if you wish to select any, use "?=" operator instead of "=".

This will work only if you have a field named "partner_id" in the same form.